# Container data values aren't coming through using a Templated User Control

Tags: asp.net, controltemplate

I have created a Templated UserControl. I don't want to bloat this post by posting all the code I used to create the control but suffice to say that I am fairly certain that the code is correct. I will post a few snippets to show that I do know the proper way to do this. First is my ITemplate implementation:

```
private ITemplate _NutritionLabelTemplate = null;
[TemplateContainer(typeof(NutritionLabelContainer))]
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
public ITemplate NutritionLabelTemplate
{
    get { return _NutritionLabelTemplate; }
    set { _NutritionLabelTemplate = value; }
}
```

Then the implementation of my INamingContainer Interface:

```
public class NutritionLabelContainer : Control, INamingContainer
{
}
```

My template markup has a Placeholder control named "phNutritionLabel_Template" and cutting through the other blah blah blah, I've got something like:

```
phNutritionLabel_Template.Controls.Clear();
if (NutritionLabelTemplate != null)
{
    NutritionLabelContainer nContainer = new NutritionLabelContainer();
    nContainer.calcium = calcium;
    nContainer.calories = calories;

    NutritionLabelTemplate.InstantiateIn(nContainer);
    phNutritionLabel_Template.Controls.Add(nContainer);
}
```

Afterward, I add this templated UserControl to my webpage and to test it I add the following code:

```
    <uc1:NutritionalLabel_Template ID="NutritionalLabel_Template1" runat="server" 
    servingSize="28"
    calories="46">
     <NutritionLabelTemplate>
        <h1>Template Calories</h1>
        <span style="font-size:large; font-style:italic;"></span>
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server">
         <%#Container.calories %>
         </asp:Label>
        <br />
     </NutritionLabelTemplate>
     </uc1:NutritionalLabel_Template>
```

When I run the page the value of #Container.calories isn't visible, it's totally blank. I've debugged my code and stepping through it I can see that the values are clearly being set in the NamingContainer of the Templated Control and that the values are being carried over to the Placeholder via the NamingContainer.

I can also verify the values are set by placing the following code in the code-behind file of the webpage and then see the values reflected on the page. But otherwise, nothing.

```
Label1.Text = NutritionalLabel_Template1.calories;
```

I have seen this problem arise before and can't remember what the cause or resolution was. Can anyone provide any pointers?

I've only created these types of controls a few times so it's a bit new to me. Any help would be appreciated. I'm stumpped.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I never received any responses to this post so regardless of why no one could provide any clues to the problem, I figured out what the problem was and thought I'd post the solution for anyone who may potentially have the similiar issue to save you some needless frustration. ;-)

Turns out that I'd forgotten to add the DataBind() method to the Page_Load event of the default page. Per Microsoft, this method ensures a binding of data from a source to a server control and it's commonly used after retrieving a dataset through a database query. But since most controls perform data binding automatically, you typically should not need to make an explicit call to this method.

However, the method is also commonly overridden when you create a custom templated data-bound control. But in my case, I overrode the PageInit in the Templated control; not the Databind method. So apparently an explicit call should be made to the method in the calling page's Page_Load event to ensure the templated control and the data are bound in this case.